# How should I signify the $y$ value of a given point

Tags: notation

This is more of a aesthetics question than maths. But if I want to use the $y$ value of a given point $P$ in an equation how to I write this? I can't really show any working since I've just googled for an answer.

Comment: The important thing is, whatever notation you choose, you should include an explanatory phrase, such as “Let $P_y$ be the $y$-coordinate of point $P$” or “We will denote the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of a point $P$ as $\operatorname{proj}_x(P)$ and $\operatorname{proj}_y(P)$, respectively.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly named the [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28mathematics%29) of $P$ over the $y$-axis, denoted by $\text{proj}_y(P)$. In the link given, note in particular the bullet *set theory* under the *applications* tab.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are using it for, you can define $P=(x,y)$ and use $y$, you can use $P_y$, you can use $\operatorname{proj}_y(P)$